# PostgreSQL tables are not creating. Unable to connect Django with database?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm deploying a Django app to Heroku. When I create a new user on user registration form in my deployed app it says the user is created but after that when I try to login through that user it says the user doesn't exist.

So the error must be in my PostgreSQL database I'm using. I downloaded PostgreSQL and created a new database of name `myblog` and connected it to my Django app. But when I run `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations` the table of my database doesn't update and remains empty.

Here's my database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'myblog',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'https://mydjangoblog.herokuapp.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
}
```

Here's my complete `settings.py file`

```
import os
import django_heroku

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'myblog/media')

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydjangoblog.herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blogapp.apps.BlogappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myblog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myblog.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'myblog',
        'USER': 'kcjpsannhsia8bbr',
        'PASSWORD': 'd11bdf3cdec79aa8ad73266e3aasjasjagsjagsjggsja0e61f8758b2526ce09e',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        'OPTIONS':{
            'max_similarity': 1,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
os.makedirs(STATIC_TMP, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(STATIC_ROOT, exist_ok=True)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blogapp:post_list'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')


AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_LOCATION = 'media'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I've already installed `psycopg2` on my environment. I'm using Django 2.2. Why isn't this working? How can I fix it?

Comment: What kind of forms/views are you using? If you're doing it manually (and not using generics), it could be that you post a confirmation, even if the database is raising an error.

Comment: does your form sets the `active` field of the `User` model to `True` during creation

Comment: also after running `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations` you still need to run `heroku run python manage.py migrate` before the changes can be applied

Comment: Yes I ran the `migrate` command as well but gone in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database won't be running on the same machine as your code, so using `https://mydjangoblog.herokuapp.com` as your PostgreSQL host doesn't make sense.

Heroku Postgres [populates an environment variable `DATABASE_URL`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#designating-a-primary-database) that contains everything you need to connect. It's structured like

```
postgres://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>
```

The easiest way to use this with Django is to use [`dj-database-url`](https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/) or [`django-heroku`](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku). Pick one and add it to your dependencies file, then modify your settings accordingly.

Using the second library there you'd add

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

to the very bottom of your `settings.py`. This takes care of setting up your database and a few other Django-specific things like Whitenoise and logging.

Comment: I didn't understand your first option and I've already added the `django_heroku.settings(locals())` in my `settings.py` file. But its still not working can you please tell me what to put in 'HOST' or just leave it empty as I'm using django_heroku?

Comment: Don't populate `HOST` at all. Let `DATABASE_URL` and `django-heroku` do their thing. Though if you're already using `django-heroku` your `DATABASES` setting likely doesn't have any impact on this. What makes you think the tables aren't being created? How are you checking that?

Comment: I'm checking those in my PgAdmin4 app of PostgreSQL.

Comment: And are you connecting to the database defined by `DATABASE_URL`? Note that Heroku won't be connected to whatever databases you have on your local machine. It's a cloud-hosted database. Try running `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL` and connecting with the credentials you get back. You can pull that string apart to get individual values like user and password as indicated in my question.

Comment: It is still not working. I've updated my answer for you now you can see my full `settings.py` file I've added `django_heroku.settings(locals()) ` Your concern is appreciated see if you can help a bit more now.

Comment: @PrateekGautam, wait, you say you tried running `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations`, but there should never be any reason to run that command on Heroku. You should `makemigrations` _locally_ and commit the generated migration files. Then run _`migrate`_ locally and on Heroku. Have you run `heroku run python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @PrateekGautam, are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: No chris. I sorted out the  problem, Sorry I forgot to update you and really thanks for the help.